# Черный экран в командной строке

Tags: консоль

Ничего не отображается в командной строке, ковырялся в настройках, когда были непонятные символы при компиляции русского текста из java файла, в итоге напоролся на новую проблему.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNxdE.png

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какая командная строка? Какая компиляция? Скрины в сам вопрос, а не по ссылке

Comment: Пртивет, в команд строке все гуд по скрину. Англиские буквы при конпиляции рабоатют ?

Answer (score 0):

Командная строка windows 10, черный экран появился после того как закрепил ярлык командной строки на панели задач, потом попробовал запустить консоль через правую кнопку мыши от "пуска" проблема решилась. Не компилировались только русские буквы, эту проблему решил с помощью кодировки 65001